# Unable to switch graphics to Nvidia On-Demand in nvidia-settings Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-prime

Whenever I try to switch my graphics to `on-demand` and reboot, it just stays at `nvidia` but when I switch to `intel` it switches to that. BTW `intel` is greyed out in nvidia-settings, I have to change that with `prime-select intel`. In short, on-demand also results to switch to `nvidia`. Actually, when I select `on-demand` profile from settings and reboot the system when I again return to the settings it shows `nvidia` profile selected. It never goes on `on-demand` profile. In previous versions of Ubuntu, it was working as expected.

[image]

Comment: "On Demand" is supposed to enable the iGPU at all times except when at least one software running requires (or is best served by) the dGPU. If that's the case then it's working as intended and the same way it would work in Windows (without the possibility of user's control).

Comment: I think I couldn't explain my question properly, I added some more details please read again.

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem with the `nvidia-drivers` as I was using old drivers `nvidia-driver-390` shipped by default with a new installation of Ubuntu and now I upgraded them to the latest version for my GPU which is `nvidia-driver-470` and now everything is perfect.